# How to sum the data of a column in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make a Jasper Report that desplays a field and at the end it sums all the numbers from it. The problem is that the column is java.lang.String because it has dashes(-) and numbers.

For example I have the column in the picture. I create a variable that sums every number of the column. For every dash it should add a zero. So for the example column the result should be sum=282.

[image]

I tried the following.

```
IF(Boolean.valueOf($F{Column}).equals("-") ? $V{Sum} = $V{Sum } + 0 :  $V{Sum}= $V{Sum} + Long.parseLong($F{Column}))
```

But it gives an error "The left-hand side of an assignement must be a variable"

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Should be something like this: `"-".equals($F{Column}) ? $V{Sum} : $V{Sum} + Long.parseLong($F{Column}))`

Comment: It is better to start with [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)